# Have same graphical Layout with all screens

Tags: android, background, position, android-linearlayout, margins

I am developping an android application and am currently working on the graphical interface of the different activities.

In an activity I have a background which is an is an image representing many shelves, and I would like to put items on those shelves. But this means I have to know the exact position of each shelf in order to position my widgets correctly "on the shelves".

Actually I used a vertical LinearLayout, that contains all shelves, each shelf being represented as an horizontal LinearLayout. Then I placed the widgets (images) using margins betweens the different layouts, and the distance are in dp. Now I tested on a Samsung and it looks like I want.

My question is : defined this way, is the graphical interface going to have the same look with different screens ? Or is it going to change depending on the device ?

Here is a part of the code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/final_shelves"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- First shelf -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/first_shelf_margin_top"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/card_11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
            android:clickable="true"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/card_12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
            android:clickable="true" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/card_12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Second shelf -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/second_shelf_margin_top"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/card_21"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
            android:clickable="true" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/card_22"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
            android:clickable="true" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/card_12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Okay I have the answer : it changes if I change the device. I tried with an another device (a Samsung Ace) and it is not working... Any idea on how should I proceed then.. I have to admit I'm a little lost I thought android:margins will be sufficient to define the positions...

Comment: let us know one thing.. do you want each shelves to be only 3 per row or it should expand depending upon the device size?

Comment: Actually I would like to always have 3 widgets on each shelf, and the size of the widget depends on the size of the screen

Comment: No issues with ur flow. U should keep individual image set for different screen densities like ldpi, mdpi hdpi and xhdpi to show the images properly on all the devices...

Comment: @sha Actually when I tested with different devices the position of the widgets changed... It is not the same... I think because margins are relative distances, so maybe I need to define the position of the widgets (and so the position of the layout) in the screen ? Is that possible ?

Comment: Some codes of what you've done would help me..... Could you please show me? @akari